# Which options are there to travel from Budapest to Sarajevo by ground?

Tags: public-transport, international-travel, overland, hungary, bosnia

I would like to know which options there are to travel by ground, not hitch hiking, between Budapest and Sarajevo.
There used to be a train, but as afaik that no longer exists.

I was already planning to stop in between the 2 cities so, making the travel in parts instead of point to point is fine.

Comment: It seems that service was interrupted due to cuts in Croatia, one option could be to pass through Serbia instead

Comment: Can someone that voted to close explain why this is off topic?

Comment: where do you see it was flagged ? Is this about WANTA perhaps ?

Comment: I WANTA beer please

Comment: @Blackbird57 I don't know if you get that option. If I click the close I can see what the reason was. Yes, it is about the WANTA - This is not a question about the best route, or most touristic route. I need to get from A to B. I state that if there are stops in between it's fine.

Comment: I think only the OP can see the close flags on their questions, I see them on mine but nowhere else

Comment: @Blackbird57 makes sense.

Comment: @Blackbird57 - I think you need 3000 reputation to see the `close` links on any question.

Comment: This is not WANTA. The question is clear and useful to other travellers.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the [Hungarian railways site](http://www.mavcsoport.hu/en) and, indeed, this train no longer exists.

<strike>There is a direct train between Budapest and Sarajevo. It takes around 12 hours. Seen in [groundedtravel](http://www.groundedtravel.com/routes/rail/europe/budapest-sarajevo-drava-intercity-train):</strike>

> Only one direct service operates each day between the two cities.
>
> While it is unlikely that this train will sell out in advance of your
> journey, it can be quite busy on Fridays and Saturdays. It can be
> helpful to buy your tickets (and seat reservations) a few days in
> advance if possible. Passengers are advised to get to the station
> early in order to find a good compartment.
>
> The return fare for this journey (which is significantly cheaper than
> the one-way fare, for some reason) is €53.60.

On the moment of writing this, I see the departure time from Budapest is 9.56 and arrives in Sarajevo at 21.16.

#### Bus

According to [Eurobusways](http://www.eurobusways.com/budapest-sarajevo-bus.html) there is no aparent direct bus connection. I did a further research with Google maps and nothing appeared.

Taking this into consideration, you may want to go through Belgrade. Note that the bus station for buses between Sarajevo and Serbian cities is not in the main Sarajevo, but in the Serbian part of it, so you need to use some extra transport to go to main Sarajevo.

See [Balkan viator](http://www.balkanviator.com/en/bus-timetables/belgrade-srb/sarajevo-bih/) for this connection.

#### Shuttle bus / car

[Rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Budapest/Sarajevo) shows that driving can be the cheapest option (70-100€), whereas a shuttle bus can be more relaxing but a bit more expensive (100-110€). The above-mentioned Eurobusways can be a good way.